# How can I find the max depth of a graph with recursive code of depth of search?

Tags: algorithm, graph, tree, depth-first-search

I solved the problem with the iterative approach but having a hard time applying the recursive approach to find the max depth of a graph.
Here is the codeforces question https://codeforces.com/problemset/problem/115/A
It needs the max depth of the graph as the solution, I guess. How, can I solve it.

Comment: Are you talking about a tree? [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42463585/finding-depth-of-a-tree), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15271072/finding-maximum-depth-of-a-tree), ...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Understanding how to calculate the depth of a Binary Tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24898929/understanding-how-to-calculate-the-depth-of-a-binary-tree)

Comment: No they are not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

according to the question you get one or more (it not said that only one employee get a -1) trees.

But i think the problem is quite simple. As you found out the max depth of the tree(s) should be the number of groups.

So after parsing the input into an array the solution would just be:

```
int employees[n];
int maxdepth = 0
for (int i = 0; i<n; ++i){
  int thisDepth = 0;
  int t = i;
  while(employees[t] != -1)
    t  = employees[t];
    thisDepth++;
  }
  if(thisDepth > maxDepth){
    maxDepth = thisDepth;
  }
}
```

A recursive approach would look like:

```
int getDepth(const int i_employeeArray[], int i_employee){
   if( i_employeeArray[i_employee] == -1 ){
     return 0;
   } else {
     return 1+ getDepth(i_employeeArray, i_employeeArray[i_employee]);
   }
}


int employees[n];
int maxdepth = 0
for (int i = 0; i<n; ++i){
  int thisDepth = getDepth(employees, i);
  if(thisDepth > maxDepth){
    maxDepth = thisDepth;
  }
}
```

Both could be optimizedby storing calculated depths for visited fields, but should not be necessary for this rather small (<=2000 employees) problem.

Comment: Nicely done @vlad_tepesch. Thank you. Was having a hard time applying the recursive approach.